A property of quadratic Gauss sums
I'm trying to show that $G(k; p^\alpha) = p G(k; p^{\alpha-2})$, where $(k, p) = 1$, $\alpha \geq 2$ and $G$ denotes the quadratic Gauss sum. I've noticed that
$$\sum_{\substack{1 \leq r \leq p^\alpha \\ (r, p) = 1}} e^{2 \pi i k r^2 / p^\alpha} = \sum_{1 \leq s \leq p^\alpha} e^{2 \pi i k s^2 / p^\alpha} - p \sum_{1 \leq s \leq p^{\alpha-2}} e^{2 \pi i k s^2 / p^{\alpha-2}}.$$
This was obtained by expanding the condition $(r, p) = 1$ using the Möbius function and interchanging the order of summation. The right-hand side happens to be exactly $G(k; p^\alpha) - p G(k; p^{\alpha-2})$, suggesting that the left-hand side should be zero. I performed several checks using Mathematica, and the results seem consistent with this. Is there a straightforward way to prove that this sum is zero?
Also, I think it is worth mentioning that the first sum resembles (up to some factor) something of the form
$$\sum_{\substack{r \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^\alpha \mathbb{Z})^\times \\ r \text{ is a QR}}} e^{2 \pi i k r / p^\alpha},$$
which could perhaps indicate why it should be zero, but I did not make any progress with this idea.

I managed to solve it on my own. The key idea is to express $r$ in the form $r = p^{\alpha - 1}t + s$, where $0 \leq t < p$ and $0 \leq s < p^{\alpha-1}$. Then, we have
$$\sum_{0 \leq r \leq p^\alpha} e^{2 \pi i k r^2 / p^\alpha} = \sum_{\substack{0 \leq t < p \\ 0 \leq s < p^{\alpha-1}}} e^{2 \pi i k \left(t^2 p^{\alpha-2} + 2ts/p + s^2/p^{\alpha}\right)}.$$
We can split this sum into
$$\sum_{0 \leq s < p^{\alpha-1}} e^{2 \pi i k s^2 / p^\alpha} \sum_{0 \leq t < p} e^{2 \pi i k (2ts) / p}.$$
Consider the inner sum. If $(s, p) = 1$, then $\{2ts \mid 0 \leq t < p\}$ forms a complete residue system modulo $p$. Consequently, the sum vanishes for these values of $s$. On the other hand, if $(s, p) \neq 1$, the sum evaluates to $p$. Thus, we have
$$p \sum_{0 \leq w < p^{\alpha-2}} e^{2 \pi i w^2 / p^{\alpha-2}}.$$
